# Подключение к Postgresql DB сайта на Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

Есть тестовый сайт на Django с подключенной Postgresql DB, все крутится на одном хосте.
Через pgAdmin видно все таблицы: моделей и дефолтные таблицы сайта.
Пытаюсь подключиться к этой ДБ и вытащить данные:

```
import psycopg2
from ххх import config

connection = psycopg2.connect(user      = config["DB_USER"],
                              password  = config["DB_PASS"],
                              host      = "127.0.0.1",
                              port      = "5432",
                              database  = config["DATABASE"])
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Print PostgreSQL Connection properties
print("DNS Param", connection.get_dsn_parameters(),"\n")

# Print PostgreSQL version
cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
record = cursor.fetchone()
print("You are connected to - ", record,"\n")
```

во ответе вроде все хорошо

```
DNS Param {'user': 'username', 'dbname': 'somdb', 'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': '5432', 'tty': '', ...} 
You are connected to -  ('PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit',)
```

Однако если попробовать прочитать дефолтные таблицы сайта

```
print("DB Info: ", cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_admin_log;"""))
print("DB Info: ", cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_content_type;"""))
print("DB Info: ", cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM django_session;"""))
```

возвращается `None`:

```
DB Info:  None
DB Info:  None
DB Info:  None
```

При обращении к таблицам моделей сайта

```
print("DB Info: ", cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM app_settings_Global_Settings"""))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/..../db_connector.py", line 27, in <module>
    print("DB Info: ", cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM app_settings_Global_Settings;"""))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "app_settings_global_settings" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM app_settings_Global_Settings;
```

Что я делаю не так?

**UPDATE:**

Вопрос заключается не в том, почему возвращается `None` на дефлтных страницах, с этим все ясно. 
Почему при чтении таблиц моделей возникает ошибка?

Comment: миграции сделали?

Comment: да, миграции сделаны, в таблицах моделей есть данные, и они без проблем туда заносятся и выгружаются через формы или CBGV

Comment: А в конфигах точно та БД указана? Не к дефолтной пустой подключаетесь?

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с [документацией psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html).

Сам `execute` не возвращает никаких данных ([документация](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute)).

Надо использовать [fetchall](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall) (или [fetchone](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchone)/fetchmany).

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(**connection_settings)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(your_sql_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()  # Извлекаем данные
for row in rows:
    process(row)
```

Comment: Вопрос наверное больше отностися вот к этому: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "app_settings_global_settings" does not exist. fetchall - работает, но только с дефолтными таблицами Djando, из таблиц моделей данные вытащить не получается

Answer (score 0):

Обратил внимание, что в ошибке имя таблицы написано lowercase. Переименование таблиц моделей с выполнением повторных миграций решило проблему с доступом к данным.

Django ver. 3.0.4

PostgreSQL 12.1

Comment: by design. потому что у вас в запросе имя таблицы без кавычек. `from app_settings_Global_Settings` и `from APP_settings_global_settings` - одно и то же. `create table "app_settings_Global_Settings"` - это другая таблица. `Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case.` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Не очень понимаю о чем Вы говорите, указание таблицы в кавычках в данном случае приведет к синтаксической ошибке                                               `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'app_set_global_settings';")` `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'app_set_global_settings'"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 'app_set_global_settings';`

Comment: ну уж как синтаксически корректно записать кавычку в строку - это сами, сами.

Comment: Ну да, идея ясна, про двойные кавычки я как-то не догадался. Спасибо! `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM \"app_set_Global_Settings\";")`